# What's the first physics textbook for undergraduate self-learner？

Tags: soft-question

I am kind of studying physics on my own now.
I choose University Physics (13th Edition) for myself,is it fine?
I am also studying Calculus using Thomas' textbook.

[http://www.amazon.com/University-Physics-13th-Edition-Young/dp/0321696891/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1352260382&sr=8-1&keywords=university+physics+13th+edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321696891)

Comment: Feynman lectures is highly recommended. I cannot comment on the book that you link to.

Comment: @Prathyush University Physics (13th Edition) By Hugh D. Young and Roger A. Freedman

Comment: If you are content with University Physics, then, Jewett' and Serway. "Physics for Scientists and Engineers with Modern Physics"

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your background.

For really starters, I'd suggest Paul Hewitt's book [Conceptual Physics](http://www.conceptualphysics.com/).

For **A** to **B** high school students, I'd say Resnick and Halliday's book is great.

For **A+** high school students, I'd recommend Feynman's Lectures. These lectures serve as complement for the other books, but personally *it's not for beginners*

Cheers.

Comment: I am no way a A+,but since almost everyone recommend Feynman,maybe I will read it after mastering textbooks.

Answer (score 0):

You can study "Modern physics" by Arthur Beiser. It is a very good book for undergraduate students. And also you can study the Feynmann Lecture series.

Answer (score -2):

Resnick/Halliday/Walker is a great book for undergraduates for self learning